# Error: Error on execute :pyx command, ultisnips feature of coc-snippets requires pyx support on vim

Tags: vim, nvim

Estoy intentando instalar neovim en mi computadora Windows, pero siempre que lo abro me sale el siguiente error:

> [coc.nvim] Error: Error on execute :pyx command, ultisnips feature of coc-snippets requires pyx support on vim.

Encontre en este [otro post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71439434/when-i-open-the-nvim-init-vim-file-this-error-comes-for-neoclide-coc-vim) que el comando `pyp install pynvim` debería solucionar mi problema, pero no lo hace.
Aquí les dejo mi una screenshot por si lo quieren ver gráficamente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mis variables de sistema tengo agregado el siguiente path:

```
C:\Users\ltomi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310
```

no se si debería agregar algún otro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok lo he solucionado.
Parece que normalmente estos errores vienen de instalar Neovim o alguno de sus plugin con versiones incompatibles. Lo que yo hice para solucionarlo fue desinstalar neovim y reinstalarlo después de actualizar todas las tecnologías necesarias a su ultima versión.
Las tecnlogías que actualice son las siguientes (no se si me falta alguna):

- Node.js
- Chocolatey
- Python
- Neovim (evidentemente)